# How to provide the instanced objects with a value field?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, custom-attributes

The specific problem I'm facing is that I have a node group (called petals array) that is instanced on a point cloud. Each point in the cloud has an anonymous attribute (say growth) which is captured and propagated down the node tree. The node group is then instanced on that point cloud but the instance on points node obviously doesn't has the input for me to plug the growth field in.
[image]
I don't want to connect the growth field to the scale input of each instance, rather I want to connect the growth field to the node group's own single valued input (which is also called Growth). Ignore the diamond symbol on Growth input of petals array, it needs to be a single value and not a field for one particular instance of this petals array node group.